MudBlazor MudGrid Spacing after breakpoints
I'm trying to create a responsive Blazor page using MudBlazor and MudGrid.  A basic representation of this issue is:
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" lg="6">
        <MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 1" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>

    <MudItem xs="12" lg="6">
        <MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 2" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>

    
</MudGrid>

<MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 3" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

<MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 4" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

@code {
    private string value = "Text Value";
}

At the larger viewport, this displays as expected:

but when you break under the large viewport, it creates a wider gap between the two fields in the grid, such as:

I am expecting the spacing to be equal across the four fields otherwise it looks odd on a smaller screen and the idea of breaking to be efficient use of screen space.
If I use the Bootstrap Flex grid the spacing is as expected but I don't want to mix frameworks and I'm pretty far down the road on MudBlazor.
Here is a try link:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuQeErmPpLzsAQuP
I've been playing around with the CSS around .mud-grid-item but it messes with the fields on lines that aren't broken and the helper text ends up sitting on top of the field below.
Any ideas?

You can use Spacing property of MudGrid to change the spacing. The default is set to 6. Setting it to 0 will remove it.
Then you can override some of the spacing by adding your own CSS to the MudGrid
<style>
    .mud-grid-custom-spacing{
        margin-top:0px !important;
        margin-left: -4px !important;
    }
    .mud-grid-custom-spacing >.mud-grid-item{
        padding-left: 4px !important;
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        
    }
</style>

<MudGrid Class="mud-grid-custom-spacing" Spacing="0">
    <MudItem xs="12" lg="6">
        <MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 1" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>

    <MudItem xs="12" lg="6">
        <MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 2" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </MudItem>

    
</MudGrid>

<MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 3" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

<MudTextField Value="@value" HelperText="Label 4" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

@code {
    private string value = "Text Value";
}

MudBlazor custom spacing snippet

Sorry, maybe my explaination was not clear.  The two text fields outside of the grid was on purpose to show how the spacing differs between grids and non-grids.  It is that extra spacing when a grid breaks I am trying to eliminate so it looks consistent.  Bootstrap grid doesn't have the same behaviour but the code is more complex in bootstrap than in mudblazor

You can use Spacing to match the other components spacing however this will change the margin-left aswell so might not be what you're after. Therefore, you can explicitly style the MudGrid to match the other components margins. The margin-top is what you should match.

RBeeL yes, I've been experimenting with Spacing and it gets me close enough.  If I set Spacing="0" the vertical alignment is exactly what I want but the two columns touch in the middle.  Spacing="1" gives me a space in the middle, the left and right hand sides are ok and it adds 4px extra in the middle which while noticeable is acceptable as you would really need to look for it.  Thanks for coming back on this.

Updated my answer to match your needs, you can customize your requirements this way.

Thank you RBee. That’s exactly what I wanted.

Thanks to RBee's reply, to clarify the accepted solution that is discussed in the comments:
Set  provides the right behaviour horizontally and only pads the space by 4px which is visually acceptable.

I believe it is better for the one who commented to write down their 'solution comment' as an answer and the OP accepting it as a solution.
